# Problems in Searching Content from table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter, project

Why this project is not working properly on searching result & by clicking on button.
here is html & javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Table Project</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="search">
        <input type="search" name="" id="inpBar">
        <button type="search" name="" id="btnBar">Search Now</button>
    </div>
    <div class="table-container">
        <table class="custom-table">
            <h2>Top American Singers</h2>
            <tbody id="table-id">
                <tr>
                    <td>Ed Sheeran</td>
                    <td>Billie Eilish</td>
                    <td>Ariana Grande</td>
                    <td>The Weeknd </td>
                    <td>Taylor Swift</td>
                    <td>Adele Laurie</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Justin Bieber</td>
                    <td>Dua Lipa</td>
                    <td>Beyonce</td>
                    <td>Lady Gaga</td>
                    <td>Bruno Mars</td>
                    <td>Celine Dion</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shawn Mendes</td>
                    <td>Rihanna</td>
                    <td>Charlie Puth</td>
                    <td>Sam Smith</td>
                    <td>Harry Styles</td>
                    <td>Miley Cyrus</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alicia Keys</td>
                    <td>Selena Gomez</td>
                    <td>Adam Levine</td>
                    <td>Joh Legend</td>
                    <td>Zayn Malik</td>
                    <td>Halsey</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jennifer Lopez</td>
                    <td>Katty Perry</td>
                    <td>Pink</td>
                    <td>Shakira</td>
                    <td>Demi Lovato</td>
                    <td>Cardi B</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p id="noResult">No Result Was Founded</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        const input = document.getElementById("inpBar");
        const button = document.getElementById("btnBar");
        const table = document.getElementById("table-id");
        const noResult = document.createElement("noResult");
        const rows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr"));
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            button.addEventListener("click", (implement) => {
                function implement() {
                    const get = input.value.toLowerCase();
                    const filtered = Array.from(rows.getElementsByTagName("td").map(cell.textContent.toLowerCase()));
                    return filtered.some(text => text.includes(get));
                    
                    table.innerHTML = "";
                    if (filtered.length > 0){
                        filtered.forEach(row => table.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true)));
                        noResult.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else {
                        noResult.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

& here is quick css of this project:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    align-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.table-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.custom-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px white;
}

.custom-table td {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    /* font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; */
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}


.search {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;
}

button {
    background-color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#inpBar {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Expected result search & got nothing. project is not working at all. whenever I try to search content in input button, and on clicking button I get nothing. I think there is a problem with braces & function (might be). try by your self & then let me know....

Comment: What is `(implement) => { function implement() { ... } }` supposed to do? You create an eventhandler, which declares a local function but never calls it. Either remove `function implement() { ` or `(implement) => {`  and the respective closing brace